# SQL Match on Username and Title

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to figure out which WHERE clause would work best for this problem. I need the query to show all the entries made by a specific user stored in the useUsername() function, unless that user has a titleID = 3 which is the Admin titleID. The titleIDs are stored in a different table called tblPlanner. I am trying to figure out if a WHERE clause or putting the theory in the useUserName() would work best. Here is the code

```
    SELECT tblClient.clientName, tblClient.clientFirmPartner, tblClient.clientRoot, tblClientPlan.offeringType, tblClientPlan.paidBy, tblClientPlan.regionalManager, tblClientPlan.plannerUser, tblClientPlan.clientID, tblClientPlan.offeringName, tblClient.clientIA, tblClient.clientAccount, tblClientPlan.lawyerName, tblClientPlan.allInfoDate
FROM tblClient INNER JOIN tblClientPlan ON tblClient.clientID = tblClientPlan.clientID
WHERE (((tblClientPlan.plannerUser)=useUserName()));
```

I am pretty new to this so any help would be great

The useUsername() function is as follows

```
Option Compare Database
Public strUserName As String

Public Function useUsername()
    useUsername = strUserName


End Function
```

It returns the value from the login form from the global variable via

```
strUserName = Me.txtUser.Value
```

The theory I have in my mind right now is as follows:

```
If (((DLookUp("tblPlanner.Title","tblPlanner","tblPlanner.userName"=useUsername()))=3)) 
then show all values, else show the above query
```

Comment: What should happen if titleID = 3 - show all records? titleID field is not in query. Functions don't "store" anything, they calculate and return a value. What is actually stored in plannerUser field - user ID? Edit question to show data as text tables. Show the code for useUserName() function.

Comment: I never use dynamic parameterized query. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I updated the question to show the code for the function. titleID is in another table and I would have to join it to the query. TitleID = 3 is just for admins, as I would like either the user or admins to access the data they have inputted.

Comment: Didn't answer question about what data is in plannerUser - numeric ID key or descriptive text. Title field is a number type? I am going to reiterate I advocate code applying filter to form or report and direct you to review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: plannerUser is a shortText. titleID is a Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use dynamic parameterized query, consider:

```
WHERE tblClientPlan.plannerUser LIKE 
IIf(DLookup("titleID", "tblPlanner", "username='" & useUsername() & "'") = 3, "", useUserName()) & "*";
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!